# Iterate through all but one elements in a form

Tags: javascript, forms

I would love my `while` to iterate through all but one of the elements in the form. This is my code:

```
while (i < elnum && !empty) {
        if (form.elements[i].value == "" && form.elements[i] != form.referral) {
            error.innerHTML += 'All fields are required.</br>';
            empty = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Where `elnum` is the number of elements.

Unfortunately, even if I leave only `form.referral` empty, it still enters inside the `if`. Basically, I want the check to be done for all fields but for that one.

Comment: something like `if(badField){continue;}` should work. Make sure it's the first statement in the if condition.

Comment: What's form.referral?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/CzFWL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to compare elements, try something like this:

```
if( form.elements[i].name == "referral") continue;
```

Put that just inside the loop, before the condition to check for an empty value.

That being said, it might be better to do something like this:

```
while(i < elnum) {
    if( form.elements[i].hasAttribute("required") && form.elements[i].value == "") {
        error.innerHTML += "All fields are required.<br />";
        // re-add `empty=true` if the variable is needed elsewhere
        // if it's only used to end the loop, then this is better:
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

And make sure you add the `required` attribute to all required fields. This is a better solution because then it will take advantage of the browser's native ability to handle HTML5 forms, if it has any.